# Subversion - 'Expected help.war to be a file but found a directory' error

Tags: svn

I had a help.war file in my project, then I decided to expand the war archive so I removed the war file and created a directory named help.war. 
But when I try to commit I'm getting "Expected help.war to be a file but found a directory error" error.

I don't want to commit twice(first after deleting the .war package and then after adding the directory). Due to some other non-technical requirements I want to be able to commit this entire change in a single commit. 
How can I do this in a single commit?
Any input would be appreciated.

Svn version : svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486) compiled Apr 11 2013, 16:13:51

Comment: AFAIK this issue has been fixed with SVN 1.7. See the release notes: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#immediate-dir-removal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it with SVN 1.7.9, and it works perfectly:

```
svn rm --keep-local help.war
# unpack help.war
svn add help.war
svn commit
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated. I can't test it at the moment but I'll test it first thing on Monday.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.7 caused some other issues but in the end it worked. I  ended up upgrading to 1.8 and it worked using 1.8, I didn't have a chance to test with v 1.7.9 Thank you